# More Efficient Way to Test for Value in Multiple Fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am doing a join to get sum values from tables that have large numbers of rows (6000+ in one and 3000 in the other).  I'm using this query to create a view.  It takes 4.5 seconds to run.  Any way I could make this quicker/more efficient?

```
SELECT SUM(ca.mkt_value) AS tot_mkt, 
        ca.customerid,
        c.customerid,
        ca.assetid
FROM cust_asset ca
JOIN customers c ON c.customerid=ca.customerid
WHERE assetid = c.port1 
        OR ca.assetid=c.port2 
        OR ca.assetid=c.port3 
        OR ca.assetid=c.port4 
        OR ca.assetid=c.port5 
        OR ca.assetid=c.port6 
        OR ca.assetid=c.port7 
        OR ca.assetid=c.port8
GROUP BY ca.customerid
ORDER BY ca.customerid, ca.assetid
```

I know this is ugly and there is better way, but I've been working on code all day and my mind is full.

Comment: Probably you can't change it, but numerated columns are most times a sign that there should be another table ...

Comment: absolutely! But I'm working with an old software model that was based upon pre-relational, flat-file logic. We imported from FoxPro.  We'll get to a better model, but for now this is the starting point.

Comment: I assume that there are rows with values in more than one portN column. That's right? Btw you should have a look at the output of EXPLAIN <your query> and add this output to your question.

Comment: I'm remotely accessing the db using sequelPro and mysql workbench, I don't have command line access for a copy and paste EXPLAIN result.  I'd have to upload a screen capture of the tabular output from those applications.

Comment: With MySQL workbench you should be able to copy the rows. It's better than screenshots.